# associating cperl-mode with Perl code in emacs

Tags: emacs, cperl-mode

I am trying to associate CPerl mode with Perl source files in emacs (23.1.1 on CentOS 6).

If I include the following line in my .emacs

```lisp
(defalias 'perl-mode 'cperl-mode)
```

then CPerl mode will be loaded when a Perl source file is opened.

However, the following line, which seems like ti should work,  results in Perl mode being loaded instead:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.p[lm]$" . cperl-mode))
```

There's no error message - it just loads Perl mode instead of CPerl mode.

The reason I'm asking is that I've had some issues using cperl-set-style (works from the emacs menu but not if I add it as a hook to the CPerl mode when it's been aliased to perl-mode) and I wanted to try loading CPerl mode directly.

The statement I'm using in my .emacs to set the indenting style as a hook to CPerl mode is

```lisp
(eval-after-load "cperl-mode" 
    add-hook 'cperl-mode-hook (lambda() (cperl-set-style 'C++))))
```

This obviously has no effect if CPerl mode is not loaded (when I use the auto-mode-alist approach) and does not do the right thing (seems to use GNU indent style) when I load CPerl mode by aliasing it to Perl mode.

Comment: I assume you forgot a `'(` before the `add-hook`.  FWIW, you shouldn't need to wrap an `add-hook` statement in `eval-after-load`, though it shouldn't hurt either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `(cperl-set-style "C++")` instead of `(cperl-set-style 'C++)`.  If you look at the variable `cperl-style-alist` (e.g. with <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>) then you will see that the `car`'s consist of strings rather than symbols.  It seems unfortunate that your example failed silently rather than raising an error.  Most of the time I would want to know that I tried to choose a non-existant style, but there's probably a good reason for it to be the way it is.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>M-:</kbd> `(info "(emacs) Choosing Modes")` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Do your perl scripts start with `#!/usr/bin/perl` ?

> Second, if there is no file variable specifying a major mode, Emacs
>   checks whether the file's contents begin with `#!'.  If so, that
>   indicates that the file can serve as an executable shell command, which
>   works by running an interpreter named on the file's first line (the
>   rest of the file is used as input to the interpreter).  Therefore,
>   Emacs tries to use the interpreter name to choose a mode.  For
>   instance, a file that begins with `#!/usr/bin/perl' is opened in Perl
>   mode.  The variable `interpreter-mode-alist' specifies the
>   correspondence between interpreter program names and major modes.

The default is perl-mode of course:

```lisp
ELISP> (assoc "perl" interpreter-mode-alist)
("perl" . perl-mode)
```

So you would simply use add-to-list again...

```lisp
(add-to-list 'interpreter-mode-alist '("perl" . cperl-mode))
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked! My scripts do start with the proper shebang line.

Comment: Good to hear; and you should 'accept' the answer, in that case.